# chaging width of one column css

Tags: html, css

Here's my css properties for a table. I want to fix the width of a certain column and hide the overflow. I tried on all the columns but i can't seem to make it work.

```
.celltable2 table {
table-layout:fixed;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
width: 640px;
border-collapse:
collapse; border-spacing: 0;
}

table.celltable2 td, th {

border: 1px solid transparent;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
transition: all 0.3s; 
overflow: hidden;
}

table.celltable2 td {

text-align:center; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Is there something i might be missing?. I tried defining colgroup and colspan but no success.

Comment: please add your html aslo.

Comment: Your CSS would indicate you're targeting a *table* and *not* a column within a table. But.. without HTML it's impossible to be certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your this css

```
table.celltable2 td, th {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: all 0.3s; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

In this you have targeted the width of `<td>` but not the `<th>` as after `,` you need to define like this `table.celltable2 th` instead of just `th`.

This is correct

```
table.celltable2 td, table.celltable2 th {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: all 0.3s; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```